# auto tabbing on the first textbox isnt working

Tags: javascript, html, textbox, credit-card

the following is code is used to create a credit card. My only promblem is that auto tabbing doesnt work for my textbox with the id of card.i have a external file for the auto tabbing and i have attached the code under the html code.Thanks in advance.

```
    <head>
    <title>Credit Card</title>

     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
     <script src="jquery.autotab.js"></script>
     <script src="Jstepper.js"></script>
    </head>
    </body oncopy="return false" oncut="return false" onpaste="return false">
    <style>
    #Month{
     width: 20px;
     }
     #Year{
     width: 40px;
     }
     #Cvc{
     width: 30px;
     }
    </style>
     <p>Payment:
         Credit card<input type="radio" id='radio_1' name='payment' value="credit">
          <div class="text1">
            <form name="cardForm" method="post">
                <p>Card number:<input type="text" name="FirstField" id='card' value="" 
                onKeyup="autotab(this,document.cardForm.SecondField)" maxlength=16 >
                Expiration: Month:-<input type="text" name="SecondField"  id='Month' value=""
                onKeyup="autotab(this,document.cardForm.ThirdField)"  maxlength=2 >
                Year:-<input type="text" id='Year' name="ThirdField" value="" onKeyup="autotab(this, document.cardForm.FourthField)"maxlength=4></p>
                3 digit CVC:-<input type="text" name="FourthField" id='Cvc' value="" maxlength=3></p>
            </form>       
          </div>    

    </body>
    <!--Jump when expiration number is typed-->
    <!--month and year-->
    <!--exp date has to greater than or equal to current date -->
    <!--on every keypress check if the length is 16-->
    <!--macthes-->
    <!-- Import numeric from src folder-->
        <script src="numeric.js"></script>
    <script>
    //autotab doesnt work for the first feild
    //can still copy and paste text
        $(document).ready(function () {
         $(".text1").hide();
            $("#radio_1").click(function () {
                    <!--passes card id to keypress function-->
                    $('#card').keypress();
                    //disable copy and paste
                    $('#card').bind();
                    $('#Month').keypress();
                    $('#Month').bind();
                    $('#Month').jStepper({minValue:0, maxValue:12});

                    $('#Year').keypress();
                    $('#Year').bind();

                    $('#Cvc').keypress();
                    $('#Cvc').bind();
                    $(".text1").show();
                }); 
            });

    </script>

<html>  

/*
Auto tabbing script- By JavaScriptKit.com
http://www.javascriptkit.com
This credit MUST stay intact for use
*/

function autotab(original,destination){
if (original.getAttribute&&original.value.length==original.getAttribute("maxlength"))
destination.focus()
}
```

Comment: Just post relevant code here and create a jsfiddle please

Answer (score 0):

```
my isnumeric file
$(this).keypress(function (e) {
    //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
});


//check for the type of credit card and prints to console
$(this).keypress(function (e) {
var input = document.getElementById('card');
input.onkeyup = function() {
   if(input.value.length == 16){

    var str = input.value;

    var VisaRegx = /^4[0-9]{6,}$/i; 
    var Visafound = str.match(VisaRegx);
    if(Visafound != null){
         console.log("Visa Found");
    }

    var MasterRegx = /^5[1-5][0-9]{5,}$/i;  
    var Masterfound = str.match(MasterRegx);
    if(Masterfound != null){
        console.log("Master Card Found");
    }
    var AmericanExpressRegx = /^3[47][0-9]{5,}$/i;  
    var AmericanExpressfound = str.match(AmericanExpressRegx);
    if(AmericanExpressfound != null){
        console.log("American Express Card Found");
    }
    //^(?:2131|1800|35[0-9]{3})[0-9]{3,}$
    var DinersClubRegx = /^3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{4,}$/i;   
    var DinersClubfound = str.match(DinersClubRegx);
    if(DinersClubfound != null){
        console.log("Diners Club Card Found");
    }
    var DiscoverRegx = /^6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{3,}$/i;    
    var Discoverfound = str.match(DiscoverRegx);
    if(Discoverfound != null){
        console.log("Discover Card Found");
    }
    var JcbRegx = /^(?:2131|1800|35[0-9]{3})[0-9]{3,}$/i;   
    var Jcbfound = str.match(JcbRegx);
    if(Jcbfound != null){
        console.log("Jcb Card Found");
    }
        } 
    }
});
//checks for credit card expiration
$(this).keypress(function (e) {
    var Monthinput = document.getElementById('Month').value;
    var Yearinput = document.getElementById('Year').value;  
    var today = new Date();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
      if(Yearinput.length == 4){
    if(yyyy > Yearinput){
        console.log("The card is expired cause of the year");
    }
      }
     if(Yearinput.length == 4 && Monthinput.length == 2){
    if(yyyy == Yearinput && mm > Monthinput){
      console.log("The card is expired cause of the current month");
        }
     }


});
//Disable copy and paste
$(this).bind("cut copy paste",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```